# What thing should be consider while choosing BLE uC

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth-low-energy, soc

I'm newbie in BLE segment need micro-controller with bluetooth (SOC). Please help me what thing should be consider while choosing SOC.

Comment: Review the data sheets. Take your time. Maybe spend a day collating information. Then spend another couple of days researching what you don't understand, then come here and ask a more specific question that won't get closed due to lack of research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no research done by the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [Link](http://www.argenox.com/bluetooth-low-energy-ble-v4-0-development/library/a-guide-to-selecting-a-bluetooth-chipset/) it describe well. Although it's not fully updated, nordic semiconductor introduces BLE 5.0 (nRF52840) as well as other companies.
You can search on their website & choose according to your need.